# How to Fix Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `style` of type `array` supplied to `Row`, expected `object`

Tags: javascript, react-native

i'm having this Error when i trying to run my project which is **Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `style` of type `array` supplied to `Row`, expected `object`**

How to fix this error in react native?

How can i solve this error in my project?
anyone can help me to fix this issues here for my project.

Thanks Your for Your Helping in Advance!

Here is my codes:

```
const TT= () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState();


const td= [
        'ID',
        'Name',
        'User Name',
        'Gmail',
        'Phone Number',
        'WebSite',
      ];
const widthArr= [40, 60, 80, 100, 120, 140,];


useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => setData(data))
      .catch((error) => console.error(error))
  }, []);



return (
    <View style={styles.container}>        
      <ScrollView horizontal={true}>
        <View>
          <Table style={{ marginTop: 20 }} 
          borderStyle={{ borderWidth: 2, borderColor: 'black' }}>
          </Table>
          <Row 
            data={td}
            widthArr={widthArr}
            style={styles.header}
            textStyle={styles.text}
          />
          <ScrollView>
            <Table borderStyle={{
              borderWidth: 2,
              borderColor: 'black'
            }}>
            {data?.map((rowData, index) => (
                  <Row
                    key={index}
                    data={rowData}
                    widthArr={widthArr}
                    style={[
                      styles.row,
                      index % 2 && {backgroundColor: '#F7F6E7'},
                    ]}
                    textStyle={styles.text}
                  />
                ))}
            </Table>
          </ScrollView>
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
  )
}
```

my error looks like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImNhK.png)

Answer (score 0):

If array is not acceptable, you can form a new style object by "[spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)" (`...`) to override the general style config.

```
<Row
  key={index}
  data={rowData}
  widthArr={widthArr}
  style={{
    ...styles.row,
    ...(index % 2 && {backgroundColor: '#F7F6E7'})
  }}
  textStyle={styles.text}
/>
```

Comment: I'm getting this Error:  TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'iter[Symbol.iterator]') once i use your suggestion.

Comment: Are you sure your `iter` object contains this Key? Since I cannot see `iter` in your code above.

Comment: **iter** i didn't use anything like it but once i use separate operator in style i get that error.

Comment: <Rows
                data={data}
                widthArr={widthArr}
                textStyle={styles.text}
              />  using this instead of my above row, i am getting the same error as my title, now how can i use to fix this?

Comment: Which library are you using for `<Row />`? Is it `react-native-table-component`? I see an [issue post](https://github.com/Gil2015/react-native-table-component/issues/145) about it.

Comment: import { Table, Row, Rows } from 'react-native-table-component';  yes

Comment: Then you may follow the [post](https://github.com/Gil2015/react-native-table-component/issues/145#issuecomment-1266366467) in github to solve your problem.